# What is the implementation of AQE on classic?

Tags: hhl-algorithm

I want run the HHL, but if the matrices are big, I need to use [HHL hybrid](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.10651.pdf), but I was not able to found an implementation or pseudo algorithm of AQE or HHL hybrid. Any solution?